# KVM GPU Passthrough NVIDIA 660TI using Seabios

Tags: kvm, gpu-passthrough

I'm using Debian 10 (Testing) with kernel 4.19.0-5_amd. I use KVM and I want to pass into my vm the NVIDIA GTX 660Ti graphics card which doesn't support UEFI. I have read a lot of tutorials about how to pass the secondary GPU on virtual machine but the things are really confusing because most of then use a graphic card which supports UEFI.

I have followed all steps from this tutotial (https://heiko-sieger.info/running-windows-10-on-linux-using-kvm-with-vga-passthrough/) and bellow I have the results:

[image]

I want to pass the device with code 03:00.0

[image]

[image]

My device doesn't contain any other device so my IOMMU group I this is correct!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In `/etc/default/grub` file, I have this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset intel_iommu=on i915.enable_hd_vgaarb=1"
```

My VM xml file is:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
<name>WIN-DEV-SRV</name>
  <uuid>7021e92f-ce81-4825-bdf9-7a5bfb84e9ef</uuid>
  <title>Windows Development Server</title>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/2k16"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-3.1'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state='on'/>
    </kvm>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/media/shared/vms/WIN_DEV_SRV_vHDD.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/media/shared/others/Windows/All files/Applications/Virtual Machines/KVM-QEMU/VirtIO drivers/virtio-win-0.1.171-latest_2019-06-01.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdc' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:07:10:77'/>
      <source bridge='bridge0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-vga'/>
    <qemu:arg value='none'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-set'/>
    <qemu:arg value='device.hostdev0.x-vga=on'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

When I start the VM with the command

```
virsh start WIN-DEV-SRV
```

the bellow error is occurred

```
error: Failed to start domain WIN-DEV-SRV
error: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2019-06-02T17:23:59.871333Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.4,multifunction=on,addr=0x0: vfio 0000:03:00.0: failed getting region info for VGA region index 8: Invalid argument
device does not support requested feature x-vga
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Why do you think that NVidia 660Ti doesn't support UEFI?

Comment: Because I have checked it with GPU-Z!

Comment: Please [don't post images as text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086). Please edit your question and replace the screenshots with plain text.